# Have/Had met before

Tags: grammar

Which is correct, "Had met before" or "have met before", in the following context:

- Hey mom, Today, I met a man named Sunil Das. He said he knew me and he said many things about me that were true. But I can't remember if I **had met him/have met** him before.

Can anyone who Is a teacher or has good knowledge of the language please answer this?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you. And Merry Christmas all the experts here.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Would you mind putting in an answer? You constantly answer in comments and it makes it very hard to keep with the rules.

Answer (score 1):

As FumbleFingers stated in the comments:

> Both are fine. The only difference is that syntactically, "if I have met him" (or more precisely, the word before) is relative to time of speaking, whereas "if I had met him" is relative to a time that's already in the past (when he said those "many things" about me). But semantically, they're more or less equivalent anyway, so don't bother over-thinking the choice.